# Си динамическое выделение памяти

Tags: c

Стандартное задание найти максимальное число в каждой строке двумерного массива и поменять его местами с элементом на главной диагонали. Вроде все правильно а в итоге выводит белиберду...

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        int row, col, max, main, i, j, d, f;

        puts("Vvedite kolichestvo strok massiva");
        scanf("%i", &row);

        puts("Vvedite kolichestvo stolbcov massiva");
        scanf("%i", &col);

        int*mas=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*row*col);

        puts("Vvedite elementi massiva");
        for(i=0;i<row;i++)
        for(j=0;j<col;j++)
        scanf("%i", (mas + i*col+j));

        puts("Ishodni masiv");
        for(i=0;i<row;i++)
        {
            puts("");

            for(j=0;j<col;j++)
            printf("%i ", mas[i*col+j]);

        }
        puts("\n");

        for(i=0;i<row;i++)
        {
            max=mas[i*col];

            for(j=0;j<col;j++)
            {
                if(mas[i*col+j]>max)
                {d=i;f=j;}
            }
            printf("%i ", max);

            main=mas[i*col+i];
            mas[i*col+i]=mas[d*col+f];
            mas[d*col+f]=main;
        }

        puts("Konechni masiv");
        for(i=0;i<row;i++)
        {
            puts("");

            for(j=0;j<col;j++)
            printf("%i ", mas[i*col+j]);

        }

        free(mas);

    }
```

Comment: уважаемый, вы бы хоть массивы случайными числами инициализировали, а не заставляли пользователя вбивать все руками

Comment: @LaKO, для каждой строки, после

     max=mas[i*col];

инициализируйте 

     d = i; f = 0;

Кстати, а при чем здесь *динамическое выделение памяти*? В заголовке вопроса.

Comment: @avp да уж глупая у меня ошибка. В названии так, потому что задание было в этой теме)Спасибо.